# linux shell and java

Tags: java, linux

I want to send a command to linux shell and get it's response with java.How can i do this?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at ProcessBuilder - [example here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10704942#10704942).

Comment: Or search this site for "java processbuilder"

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the `Runtime` class, and its `exec()` family of methods.

It's probably best to explicitly specify that you want to run the command through a shell, i.e. create [a command line](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash) like `"bash -c 'my command'"`.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: Could you expand on why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Execute a process like this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
```

...then you could get the process input stream and read it with a Reader to get the response

Answer (score 0):

See the [Runtime](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class and the [exec()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Note that you need to consume the process's stdout/sterr *concurrently*, otheriwse you'll get peculiar blocking behaviour. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little class to do this in a very similar question a couple of weeks ago:

[java shell for executing/coordinating processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596396/java-shell-for-executing-coordinating-processes/1596842#1596842)

The class basically let's you do:

```
    ShellExecutor excutor = new ShellExecutor("/bin/bash", "-s");
    try {
            System.out.println(excutor.execute("ls / | sort -r"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```