# Difference between ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute an external command from java code, but there's a difference I've noticed between `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` and `new ProcessBuilder(...).start()`.

When using `Runtime`:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(installation_path + 
                                       uninstall_path + 
                                       uninstall_command + 
                                       uninstall_arguments);
p.waitFor();
```

the exitValue is 0 and the command is terminated ok.

However, with `ProcessBuilder`:

```
Process p = (new ProcessBuilder(installation_path +    
                                 uninstall_path +
                                 uninstall_command,
                                 uninstall_arguments)).start();
p.waitFor();
```

the exit value is 1001 and the command terminates in the middle, although `waitFor` returns.

What should I do to fix the problem with `ProcessBuilder`?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The various overloads of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` take either an array of strings or a single string.  The single-string overloads of `exec()` will tokenise the string into an array of arguments, before passing the string array onto one of the `exec()` overloads that takes a string array.  The `ProcessBuilder` constructors, on the other hand, only take a varargs array of strings or a `List` of strings, where each string in the array or list is assumed to be an individual argument.  Either way, the arguments obtained are then joined up into a string that is passed to the OS to execute.

So, for example, on Windows,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\DoStuff.exe -arg1 -arg2");
```

will run a `DoStuff.exe` program with the two given arguments.  In this case, the command-line gets tokenised and put back together.  However,

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("C:\DoStuff.exe -arg1 -arg2");
```

will fail, unless there happens to be a program whose name is `DoStuff.exe -arg1 -arg2` in `C:\`.  This is because there's no tokenisation: the command to run is assumed to have already been tokenised.  Instead, you should use

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("C:\DoStuff.exe", "-arg1", "-arg2");
```

or alternatively

```
List<String> params = java.util.Arrays.asList("C:\DoStuff.exe", "-arg1", "-arg2");
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder(params);
```

Comment: it still doesn't work: List<String> params = java.util.Arrays.asList(installation_path+uninstall_path+uninstall_command, uninstall_arguments);
   Process qq=new ProcessBuilder(params).start();

Comment: I can not believe that this string concatanation makes any sense: "installation_path+uninstall_path+uninstall_command".

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) does *NOT* invoke a shell unless that is explicitly specified by the command. That is a good thing regarding the recent "Shellshock" bug issue. This answer is misleading, because it states that cmd.exe or equivalent (i.e. /bin/bash on unix) would be run, which does not seem to be the case. Instead tokenization is done inside the Java environment.

Comment: @noah1989: thanks for the feedback.  I've updated my answer to (hopefully) clarify things and in particular remove any mention of shells or `cmd.exe`.

Comment: the parser for exec doesn't work quite the same as a the parameterized version either, which took me a few days to figure out...

Comment: @DrewDelano - yea.  The "parser" is effectively `String.split("\\s+")` :-)

Answer (score 23):

There are no difference between `ProcessBuilder.start()` and `Runtime.exec()` because implementation of `Runtime.exec()` is:

```
public Process exec(String command) throws IOException {
    return exec(command, null, null);
}

public Process exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)
    throws IOException {
    if (command.length() == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty command");

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(command);
    String[] cmdarray = new String[st.countTokens()];
    for (int i = 0; st.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
        cmdarray[i] = st.nextToken();
    return exec(cmdarray, envp, dir);
}

public Process exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)
    throws IOException {
    return new ProcessBuilder(cmdarray)
        .environment(envp)
        .directory(dir)
        .start();
}
```

So code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
new StringTokenizer(command)
.asIterator()
.forEachRemaining(str -> list.add((String) str));
new ProcessBuilder(String[])list.toArray())
            .environment(envp)
            .directory(dir)
            .start();
```

should be the same as:

```
Runtime.exec(command)
```

Thanks **dave_thompson_085** for comment

Comment: But the Q doesn't call that method. It (indirectly) calls `public Process exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)` -- `String` NOT `String[]` -- which calls `StringTokenizer` and puts the tokens in an array which is then passed (indirectly) to `ProcessBuilder`, which IS a difference as correctly stated by the three answers from 7 years ago.

Comment: It does not matter how old the question is. But i try to fix answer.

Comment: I can not set the environment for ProcessBuilder. I can only get the environment...

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO() to set environment after getting them via environment method...

Comment: If you look more carefully you could see that environment by default is null.

Comment: There is three overloaded methods `exec`.

Answer (score 20):

Look at how `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` passes the String command to the `ProcessBuilder`. It uses a tokenizer and explodes the command into individual tokens, then invokes `exec(String[] cmdarray, ......)` which constructs a `ProcessBuilder`.

If you construct the `ProcessBuilder` with an array of strings instead of a single one, you'll get to the same result.

The `ProcessBuilder` constructor takes a `String...` vararg, so passing the whole command as a single String has the same effect as invoking that command in quotes in a terminal:

```
shell$ "command with args"
```

Answer (score 19):

Yes there is a difference.

- The [`Runtime.exec(String)` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) takes a single command string that it splits into a command and a sequence of arguments.
- The [`ProcessBuilder` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder%28java.lang.String...%29) takes a (varargs) array of strings.  The first string is the command name and the rest of them are the arguments.  (There is an alternative constructor that takes a list of strings, but none that takes a single string consisting of the command and arguments.)

So what you are telling ProcessBuilder to do is to execute a "command" whose name has spaces and other junk in it.  Of course, the operating system can't find a command with that name, and the command execution fails.

Comment: No, there is not a difference. Runtime.exec(String) is a shortcut for ProcessBuilder. There are other constructors supported.

Comment: You are incorrect.  Read the source code!  `Runtime.exec(cmd)` is effectively a shortcut for `Runtime.exec(cmd.split("\\s+"))`.  The `ProcessBuilder` class does not have a constructor that is a direct equivalent to `Runtime.exec(cmd)`.  This is the point I am making in my answer.

Comment: In fact, if you instantiate a ProcessBuilder like this: `new ProcessBuilder("command arg1 arg2")`, the `start()` call will not do what you expect.  It will probably fail, and will only succeed if you have a command with spaces in its name.  This is precisely the problem that the OP is asking about!