# Runtime.exec can't work on JDK 7u25

Tags: java, process, java-7

After update java to latest version 7u25, the runtime.getruntime().exec can't work anymore.

```
//jhghai_w.filepath = "C:\\aucs\\data\\tmp.txt";
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec("CMD.EXE /C \"C:\\Program Files\\juman\\juman.exe \" -e < "+jhghai_w.filepath)
                    .getInputStream()));
```

I already read the reference:JDK 7u25: Solutions to Issues caused by changes to Runtime.exec
https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/changes_to_runtime_exec_problems

and tried some modifications as below:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec("CMD.EXE /C \"C:\\Program Files\\juman\\juman.exe  -e < \""+jhghai_w.filepath)
                    .getInputStream()));
```

and this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[] {"cmd","/C" "C:\\Program Files\\juman\\juman.exe"-e < "，jhghai_w.filepath})
                    .getInputStream()));
```

and this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[] {"cmd","/C" "C:\\Program Files\\juman\\juman.exe","-e“，”<"，jhghai_w.filepath})
                    .getInputStream()));
```

and this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[] {"cmd","/C" "\"C:\\Program Files\\juman\\juman.exe"","\"-e < \""，jhghai_w.filepath})
                    .getInputStream()));
```

I even replace the "jhghai_w.filepath" to "C:\aucs\data\tmp.txt" directly.
But the are not working. What's the problem in my modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your command to Runtime.exec() or your ProcessBuilder as a String-Array with three elements: the command as the first, "/C" as the second and the command to be executed in cmd as the third element:

```
String[] command = new String[3];
command[0] = "CMD.EXE";
command[1] = "/C";
command[2] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\juman\\juman.exe \" -e < "+jhghai_w.filepath;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.start();
```

See also [this blogpost](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/changes_to_runtime_exec_problems) especially this section:

---

The Golden Rule:

In most cases, cmd.exe has two arguments: "/C" and the command for interpretation.

---

Edit: updated solution....

Comment: @user1629420: You're right, I updated my suggestion - it does work better in my testcase...

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `Runtime.exec()` to begin with, for practical purposes is deprecated. Better switch to using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). There are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec) of [tutorials](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-run-external-programs-by-using-java-processbuilder-class/189) to show you the way.