# execute scpt file from java with parameter

Tags: java, macos, applescript

How to call .scpt(applescript) file from java and pass argument into scpt file from java using
`Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` method.

```
Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);

String[] args = {"/usr/bin/osascript", "/Users/uname/Library/Preferences/WebApp/Local\\ Store/spawn/Terminal.scpt" "args1", "args2" "args3" "false"}; 

Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

Comment: Your question don't sound very descriptive. Yeah Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd) can be used to execute any script/command. But what is your problem? what is cmdArray above?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot check this on Mac but the following answer works on windows:

```
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    list.add("java");
    list.add("-version");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream())));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

You can also read:

- [Difference between ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html