# How to pass arguments to shellscript using java?

Tags: java, shell

I am calling a shell script from java code using :

```
ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/home/abhijeet/sample1.sh ");
Process script_exec = pb2.start();
```

Which runs successfully,But i need to pass some parameters to it , so I need to execute this script as :

```
param1=abc param2=xyz /home/abhijeet/sample1.sh
```

I have tried this code:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/home/abhijeet/sample1.sh ","param1=abc","param2="xyz");
```

But it  did't work for me.How can i pass arguements to shell script while using Processbuilder for calling it?

Note:My question is about passing arguments to shellscript ,not to commands.i have read that suggested possible duplicate question , but that does't solve my problem,I tried it that way, that is for passing arguements to commands, not for shellscript

Comment: Have you tried the obvious: `ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/home/abhijeet/sample1.sh param1=abc param2=xyz");`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec)

Comment: @SirTroll: i have read that , but that does't solve my problem,I tried it that way, that is for passing arguements to commands, not for shellscript

Comment: @Smutje : yes i have tried that, it throws java.io.IOException

Comment: The code you "tried" would give you a syntax error.

Comment: @user1071777- yes,but than what's the right way of doing it?

Comment: You can use [Apache commons exec library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21793314/1686291) also.

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar : i want to do this using processbuilder,Is there any way for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you need to run the command:

```
param1=abc param2=xyz /home/abhijeet/sample1.sh
```

In this case, the "param1" and "param2" strings aren't command-line arguments. This is shell syntax to set the two *environment variables* `param1` and `param2` and then invoke `sample1.sh`.

To accomplish this with `ProcessBuilder`, you need to access the builder's environment variables:

```
ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/home/abhijeet/sample1.sh");
pb2.environment().put("param1", "abc");
pb2.environment().put("param2", "xyz");
Process script_exec = pb2.start();
```

As an alternative, the command that you're trying to run uses shell syntax, so you could pass it to a shell to execute it:

```
ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder(
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "param1=abc param2=xyz /home/abhijeet/sample1.sh");
Process script_exec = pb2.start();
```