# How to execute cmd commands through java

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, exec, selenium-grid

I have jar file(**selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar**) kept at c:\ drive.
I need to navigate to C drive and execute below command through java

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub

Comment: `Runtime.exec("cd C:\"); Runtime.exec("java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub")`

Comment: `Runtime` will definitely work.  If you want more control (like the ability to handle standard in/out), [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) will give you more.  [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6856659/2494555) some info contrasting the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code

```
 Process process  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub");
```

However this will run executable jar from your current directory, where you .class file exist.