# Java trouble executing a process(Windows)

Tags: java, process, execution, processbuilder

I need to run a native windows executable with some parameters:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        programFolder + SUB_PATH,
        params);

pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

try {
    System.out.println("running...");

    Process p = pb.start();

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
        String in = null;
        while (p.isAlive() && (in = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(in);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.

I checked that the generated command is correct and running fine when executed manually, but it seem like the above `Process` isn't executed at all and no `error`'s or `Exception`'s are `throw`'n.

**What am I missing here?**

**EDIT:** my problem isn't that the `executable` is not found but it's just not running.

**EDIT:** `params` value is:

```
String params = String.format("%d %s %s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
                            3,
                            videoPath,
                            bgImagePath,
                            distPath,
                            x1, y1, w1, h1,
                            x2, y2, w2, h2);
```

**UPDATE:** I replaced the `ProcessBuilder` with:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(programFolder + SUB_PATH + " " + params, null, programDir);
```

and it now works fine...

I still want to know **Why using the `ProcessBuilder` did not work?**

Comment: What parameters are passed to ProcessBuilder ?

Comment: @Berger please see edit...

Comment: Pass each parameter separately instead of a concatenated string.

Comment: @assylias Indeed that solves the issue... Thank you! Can you expand on this issue? The generated command is exactly the same as the one with the parameters in one `String` yet now it works...

Comment: Not that I mind the downvote but at least take a moment to comment on it so my next question will improve...

Comment: @DimaMaligin I didn't downvote and I don't know why you got a downvote - your question is fine. As to why you need to send each arg separately vs as a concatenated string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6856659/829571

Comment: @assylias Thank you. I wasn't implying that you wore the one who downvoted, otherwise I would have tagged you... Thank you again...