# What is the difference between running by creating a process and running through command line?

Tags: java, process, command

I have a jar file. I am running this jar file by *creating a process*. So, what is the difference between running it through `command prompt` without creating a process? Will it affect the application's performance?

Comment: Could you please explain,what do you mean by creating a process?

Comment: Process gateProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); so here I am running external jar by creating a process

Answer (score 0):

If your application requires you to run the jar file as a command in a separate process from your java application,It's the way to go.There is no question of performance.
However when you launch command prompt through `Runtime.exec()`,command line will be executed as a sub-process or a separate process in a random layer. 
I'd rather recommend you to use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html),however it's a different topic.

For difference between `Runtime.exec()` and ProcessBulilder please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec)