# java and wmctrl to resize windows

Tags: java, wmctrl

I'm writing a library to cover WMctrl shell program. I have problem with resizing windows:

```
String command = "wmctrl -r \"Calculator\" -e 0,100,100,500,500";

System.out.println(command);
String output = this.bashCommandExecutor.execute(command);
System.out.println(output);
```

This doesn't work - *output* variable is empty. But when I copy-paste *wmctrl -r "Calculator" -e 0,100,100,500,500* to the Terminal it works properly.

Other commands like "*wmctrl -d*" and "*wmctrl -l*" work in *this.bashCommandExecutor.execute()* method.

This method looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class BashCommandExecutor
{
    String execute(String bashCommand)
    {
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(bashCommand);
            p.waitFor();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
        );

        String line = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Why does resizing work in command line, but doesn't work in Java app?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using the ProcessBuilder class rather than Runtime.exec() works to run the wmctrl command you described.
So rather than:

```
String bashCommand = "wmctrl -r \"Calculator\" -e 0,100,100,500,500";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(bashCommand);
```

You can try:

```
String bashCommand = "wmctrl -r \"Calculator\" -e 0,100,100,500,500";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", bashCommand);
Process p = pb.start();
```

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6856659/12104701) to another post explaining the different between Runtime.exec() and using ProcessBuilder.