# Running a shell script using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, linux, process, builder

I am trying to run a script using Java and ProcessBuilder. When I try to run, I receive the following message: error=2, No such file or directory.

I dont know what I am doing wrong but here is my code (ps: I tried to execute just the script without arguments and the error is the same:

```
String[] command = {"/teste/teste_back/script.sh, "+argument1+", "+argument+""};
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    try {  

        // create a process builder to send a command and a argument
        Process p2 = p.start(); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        log.info("Output of running " + command + " is: ");
        System.out.println("Output of running " + command + " is: ");
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            log.info(line);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing

```
String[] command = {"/teste/teste_back/script.sh, "+argument1+", "+argument+""};
```

with

```
String[] command = {"/teste/teste_back/script.sh", argument1, argument};
```

Refer [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for more information.

> ProcessBuilder(String... command)
>
> Constructs a process builder with the specified operating system
>   program and arguments.

Comment: Actually the problem were the quotation on the final of my string and also with arguments.

Comment: @JaganathanNanthakumar Hi , in my shellscript there is user and pw as arguments. But how do I initialize them? when I put them into the String command the program does not know what "user" and "pw" is...? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can define a method with ProcessBuilder.

```
public static Map execCommand(String... str) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(str);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    if (process != null) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    }

    String line;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        if (reader != null) {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (process != null) {
            process.waitFor();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (process != null) {
        map.put(0, String.valueOf(process.exitValue()));
    }

    try {
        map.put(1, stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        if (stringBuilder.toString().length() == 0) {
            return map;
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

You can call the function to execute shell command or script

```
String cmds = "ifconfig";
String[] callCmd = {"/bin/bash", "-c", cmds};
System.out.println("exit code:\n" + execCommand(callCmd).get(0).toString());
System.out.println();
System.out.println("command result:\n" + execCommand(callCmd).get(1).toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless your script.sh has a comma in its name, that is the mistake:

```
String[] command = {"/teste/teste_back/script.sh" , argument1, argument};
```