# How to run brew command through java program?

Tags: java, bash, io, runtime

So I just installed the 'brightness' utility package using homebrew (its basically a way to adjust screen brightness through terminal), but I'm having a hard time running this code in java:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("brightness -l");
```

When I run "brightness -l" through terminal, it gives the current screen brightness level. But when I try the line through java it throws this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "brew": error=2, No such file or directory

I've tried the following:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/ brightness -l");
```

but it gives me a permission denied error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/usr/local/bin/": error=13, Permission denied

So I guess it'll work if I grant permission to regular users to access bin. But thats too risky, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Ummm ... "/usr/local/bin" is a directory.  That is why you can't execute it!   Regular users should have "r_x" permissions on it anyway.  Note that "x" doesn't mean execute for a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax that worked for me was:

```
String command = "echo $(/usr/local/Cellar/brightness/1.2/bin/brightness -l) >    /Users/nizhabib/Desktop/FileName";
    Process po = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", command).start();
```

Where the 'command' variable holds the directory that includes the executable 'brightness' and '-l' is a flag for the function 'brightness'. The command simply pours the output of 'brightness -l' into the text file 'FileName'.

in 'process po' we specify the type of the file in the first argument which in this case is 'sh' for **shell script** and -c to specify that '/usr/local/Cellar/brightness/1.2/bin/brightness -l' is to be handled as a **string** (because the path expression is arbitrary)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your method is that you are not running command through bash exclusively.
So my Solution would be something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c brightness -l");
```

Moreover from it is advisable to use ProcessBuilder instead because usage of Runtime.exec() is now discouraged [look the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29)

So my final solution would be :

```
String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "brightness" ,"-l"};
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
```

for more examples of ProcessBuilder [see this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570827/running-a-shell-script-using-processbuilder)

Comment: 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c brightness -l");' isn't working, so I tried creating a bash file to execute the command but when I run the bash file my reader returns null. Do you think its a problem with my reader or the Runtime line itself?  'while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {  if(line.includes.........)  }

Comment: try running some other command as like to open a application...maybe there is some problem with brightness itself

Comment: I added an echo line to the bash file to see if its even running the bash file, but I guess its not. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash <FILE_NAME>"); is returning null for some reason.

Comment: I turned <FILE_NAME> into an sh, but for some reason java is still not giving me any output.
*#!/bin/sh
echo "hi"
brightness -l*
it wont even return "hi"