# Basic FFmpeg Conversion Error?

Tags: java, file, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an .mp4 to a .opus file using ffmpeg. I have a directory on my desktop called `Indexing` which has a test file called `40.mp4`. I've tried using the command `ffmpeg -i 40.mp4 -b:a 320k 40.opus` which always works from a terminal set in the Indexing directory, but trying the same thing using Java always fails:

NOTE: I'm running on Kubuntu 17.10

`private static final Path INDEXING_PATH = Paths.get("/home/sarah/Desktop/Indexing");`

> `Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg -i 40.mp4 -b:a 320k 40.opus")
>                   .directory(INDEXING_PATH.toFile()).inheritIO().start();`

Yields:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ffmpeg -i 40.mp4 -b:a 320k 40.opus" (in directory "/home/sarah/Desktop/Indexing"): error=2, No such file or directory
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)`

Here's a snapshot of the folder:
[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Is ffmpeg in your path? (you can check by just running a straight "ffmpeg" that should work...) Possibly your ProcessBuilder constructor needs to be split up like `new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is looking for a program called `ffmpeg -i 40.mp4 -b:a 320k 40.opus` when in reality it should invoke `ffmpeg` with `-i 40.mp4 -b:a 320k 40.opus` as arguments

To fix this, change 
`Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg -i 40.mp4 -b:a 320k 40.opus")
                  .directory(INDEXING_PATH.toFile()).inheritIO().start();`

to

`Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i", "40.mp4", "-b:a", "320k",  "40.opus")
                  .directory(INDEXING_PATH.toFile()).inheritIO().start();`

Look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec) for more

Also, try adding the full path to ffmpeg in the `ffmpeg` portion of the command

Comment: I'll give it a try. I didn't think that Runtime.exec and ProcessBuilder were different.

Comment: They do have subtle differences. The answer I linked goes into great detail

Comment: In that case could you accept the answer when it becomes eligible?  :)

Comment: Should I delete the question? This isn't necessarily a duplicate of the post you linked, and it might help other people who run into the same issue. Although it is a mis-conception of it.

Comment: It's up to you. :)

Comment: I'll leave it open,  I think it can help other people who run into the same issue.